# Audio and video recorder in html5 using getusermedia()

Tags: html

I am creating a application to record audio and video,But it works only in Google chrome or canary.I want to work under Internet explorer and Mozilla Firefox.This is my code.
can we do it without using get user media?if yes please tell me.

pls refer this link
http://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaStreamRecorder is a WebRTC API for recording getUserMedia() streams . It allows web apps to create a file from a live audio/video session.

MediaStreamRecorder is currently unimplemented. you should wait for implementing it in all browsers.

```
 <video autoplay></video>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function onVideoFail(e) {
        console.log('webcam fail!', e);
      };

    function hasGetUserMedia() {
      // Note: Opera is unprefixed.
      return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    }

    if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
      // Good to go!
    } else {
      alert('getUserMedia() is not supported in your browser');
    }

    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || 
                             navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                              navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                               navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var streamRecorder;
    var webcamstream;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        webcamstream = stream;
    //  streamrecorder = webcamstream.record();
      }, onVideoFail);
    } else {
        alert ('failed');
    }

    function startRecording() {
        streamRecorder = webcamstream.record();
        setTimeout(stopRecording, 10000);
    }
    function stopRecording() {
        streamRecorder.getRecordedData(postVideoToServer);
    }
    function postVideoToServer(videoblob) {

        var data = {};
        data.video = videoblob;
        data.metadata = 'test metadata';
        data.action = "upload_video";
        jQuery.post("http://www.kongaraju.in/uploadvideo.php", data, onUploadSuccess);
    }
    function onUploadSuccess() {
        alert ('video uploaded');
    }

    </script>

    <div id="webcamcontrols">
        <button class="recordbutton" onclick="startRecording();">RECORD</button>
    </div>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/

Comment: gettign "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<LocalMediaStream> has no method 'record'." error. Do we need to include any libraries? As of now, can we record video along with audio using HTML5, even in chrome?

Comment: this API is still under implementation. try with chrome canary!

Comment: in that case is it possible to capture video in current browsers using flash ?

Comment: The MediaStream Recording API is implemented in Firefox Nightly, for audio at least -- I wrote a demo at http://www.simpl.info/mediarecorder. There's an Intent to Implement for Chrome: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/blink-dev/2l_G_apqk30

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: webcamstream.record is not a function
    at startRecording:  IN Chrome